# Call to undefined function http_get()

Tags: wampserver, http-get, pecl

I have installed `WAMPServer` and tried the PHP function; `http_get()`. I then get the following error message:

> Call to undefined function http_get()

I have done the following:

- Copied `php_http.dll` in `wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext` folder.
- Added this line: `extension=php_http.dll` to my `php.ini` file.

Comment: I donwnloaded php_http.dll from here : [http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/2.0.1/](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/2.0.1/)

Comment: If you look closely at the repository you used. **There is no version that will work with PHP5.6!** Try [this repo instead](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/2.6.0/logs/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly : there is no .dll file in your repository.

Comment: Hmm Thats useful isn't it?